# Complex Numbers Solving Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z=1+i$.

($i$) Calculate $\alpha$ such that $z^{2} + \alpha z + \alpha = 0$

($ii$) Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, find all $y \in \mathbb C$, such that $y^2 + \alpha y +  \frac{{\alpha}^2}{4}=0$

My solution:
($i$) I set $\alpha= x + iy$ and subbed in before equating coefficients. I ended up with $\alpha = \frac{-2}{5} - \frac{4}{5}i$. I was unsure whether this is correct as the question doesn't specify that $\alpha $ should be $\mathbb C$.

($ii$)I completed the square and ended up with $y = -\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Would this be an acceptable answer - would it give all solutions for $y \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: In part (i), the equation is linear in $ \ \alpha \ \ , $ so you can also solve directly that $$   \alpha \ \ = \ \ -\frac{z^2}{z \ + \ 1} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{2i}{2 \ + \ i} \ \ , \ $$ which is equivalent to your answer. $ ( \ \alpha \ $ would have to be complex in order for the left side of the equation to equal zero, in order to "zero out" both the real and imaginary parts.)  The left side of the equation in part (ii) _is_ the "binomial-square"  $$ \left( \ y \ + \ \frac{\alpha}{2} \ \right)^2 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , \ $$ leading to your answer.

Comment: The problem statement is a bit careless, as $ \ \alpha \ $ in part (i) does not need to be the same as in part (ii).

Comment: @boojum The second part I did by completing the square like you did. The first part I did as I stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions of $\alpha$ and $y$ are correct. [See this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5By%2C2%5D%2B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B-2%2C5%5D-Divide%5B4i%2C5%5D%5C%2841%29y%2BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-Divide%5B2%2C5%5D-Divide%5B4i%2C5%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C4%5D%3D0) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%291%2Bi%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2Balpha%5C%2840%291%2Bi%5C%2841%29%2Balpha%3D0)

The second link is of $\alpha$ and first one is for $y$

Comment: Okay thank you. I was unsure about $ii$ but I believe I am right now. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome${}{}$

Comment: Question: I am confused with $ii$ because it says let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. Does this mean $\alpha$ takes the same value as in $i$? If so, it was already complex in $i$, so wasn't stating that unecessary ?

Comment: As you can see from the links, alpha can't belong to real numbers. Maybe it is written like **Let alpha belong to C...** because if it were not, then maybe students tend to give **no alpha exists** as the answer...because complex numbers are not taken into domain while solving problems if it is not explicitly mentioned

Comment: Okay that makes sense. In $ii$, is it okay to give the solution as I did as I think they were referring to $\alpha \in \mathbb$ as being any complex number and not just the one I solved for in $i$?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin yes that will be okay